# ionic 3 geolocation Position error in ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, permissions, geolocation, ionic3

I'm developing `Hybrid` app using ionic-3. I'm implement `google map` and trying to get current location in my app. Map is working fine in android and browser but when i build it in ios i'm getting error of permission. I have added config-file for permission in `config.xml`

> config-file in Config.xml

```
    <config-file file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>To get your location and provide better service</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
        <string>To get your location and provide better service</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>need camera to take your profile picture</string>
    </config-file>
```

> I'm getting error as like below images

[image]

[image]

Can you suggest me any solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you passing options to Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()?

Comment: Yes, my code is as like this "Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {}"

Comment: Try this.    let options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true}; 
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then((resp) => { console.log("position", resp) }).catch((error) => { console.log('error: ', error); });

Make sure to use latest plugin and your location gps  is 'ON' in your iPhone Device

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't help. i'm getting following Error now.
"Operation could not be completed(KCLErrorDomain error 0)"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution.
I only need to set my simulators current location. i'll explain it, may be it will help someone else.

1. Run project in iPhone Simulator
2. Under the Debug menu, the last entry is "Location"; this gives you a sub menu
3. Select "Custom Location"
4. Set your location. That's it

[image]